# Морфема -ех- в слове «трехэтажный»

Tags: словообразование, морфология, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Чем является морфема -ех- в слове *трехэтажный*? Стоит ли ее вообще выделять?

На мой взгляд, это застывшее окончание, которое, может быть, и не стоит выделять, хотя и его выделение не вызовет ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На этот счет существуют разные точки зрения. Некоторые авторы считают морфему-"ех"- соединительной гласной,интерфиксом **(см.например:Тихонов А. Н. Морфемно-орфографический словарь. — М. : Шк.-пресс, 1996. — 701с.).**

Согласно другой точки зрения морфема-ех- является окончанием **(Е. И. Литневская. «Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников»).**

В книге **"Русский язык 10-11 классы" Н.Г. Гольцова, И.В. Шамшин,** морфема-ех рассматривается как часть корня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]